# get name of file in android kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, reflection, mirror

I have an Extention function in file with the name StringEx.kt.

**StringEx.kt**

```
package com.example
        
fun String.addUnderline(): String {
    return "_" + this + "_"
}
```

how can get the name and package of the file("StringEx.kt") in other class?

for example:

```
println(StringEx:class.name)
// print com.example.StringEx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here your not creating a class. instead your just creating extension function and without class how can u get its package name. class "String" not belongs to "com.example" package